# How to restore previous workflow after jboss server restart

Tags: jbpm

I have the jbpm workflow process like that 
1.Apply by jame -> 2.Approved by john -> 3.Approved by mary.

In a normal case, jame completes the task and then the new task arrived to john. And john completes the task and then new task arrived to mary. And mary completes the task.Workflow process is finished.

But in error case, jame completes the task and then the new task arrived to john. At that time jboss server restarts. After restarting jboss server, john can complete the task that is created before server restarted but the workflow process stops here and mary don't recieve new task. In order to complete workflow, mary need to complete the task but mary don't recieve any task. This is the problem.

I think that I need to restore the kSession and processInstances that are created before server restarts. But I don't know how to restore kSession.

If somebody knows how to restore kSession, kindly let me know.

Comment: Hi Wai, were you able to restore your kSession? If yes, can you please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

How you are creating kSession? you need to provide configuration also.
You need to create your session like below and check if it works.

```
final StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(knowledgeBase, null,createEnvironment());
```

Comment: I created the kSession in my apring-beans.xml.

Comment: kSession configuration spring-beans.xml is as follows.<jbpm:ksession id="ksession" type="stateful" kbase="kbase">  
     <jbpm:configuration>
         <jbpm:jpa-persistence>  
             <jbpm:transaction-manager ref="transactionManager" />  
                <jbpm:entity-manager-factory ref="entityManagerFactory" />  
   </jbpm:jpa-persistence>  
  </jbpm:configuration>  
 </jbpm:ksession> I can create kSession and do the workflow process normally if the jboss server did not restart. But if the jboss server restarted, the workflow process terminated unsuccessfully like above E.g I described.